# How to show a certain list when I click on a certain category?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I’m new to React and am struggling on this problem. Each category in my horizontal scroller should have a list. When I click on a category I would like to display that list? Currently my list is a different component to my horizontal scroller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The code is below

```
The App
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/nav_bar/navbar';
import List from './components/list';
import BottomNavbar from './components/bottom_navbar/bottomNavbar';
import HorizantScroller from './components/horizontal_scroll/horizontalscroll';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';



class App extends Component {


  render() {
    const list = {};
    const bottomNavbar = {};
    const horizantscroller = {};


    return(
      <div>
        <HorizantScroller horrizontalScroller={horizantscroller}/>
        <List list={list}/>
        <BottomNavbar bottomNavbar={bottomNavbar}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;

Horizontal Scroller Component
import React from 'react';
import ScrollMenu from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import './horizontalscroll.css';

// list of items
const list = [
  { name: 'Brands' },
  { name: 'Restaraunts' },
  { name: 'Films' }
];

// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="menu-item"
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = (list) => list.map(el => {
  const { name } = el;

  return (
    <MenuItem
      text={name}
      key={name}
    />
  );
});


const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
    >{text}</div>
  );
};


const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: '<', className: 'arrow-prev' });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: '>', className: 'arrow-next' });

class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: 0
  };

  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });
  }


  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(list, selected);

    return (
      <div className="HorizantScroller">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;


The list component

import React from "react";
import "./list.css";

class List extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        list: ["Dark Night", "Whiplash", "Inception", "Moonlight", "Gladiator", "SpiderMan", "Batman", "Hulk", "Avengers", "Normal People", "Inbetweeners"]
      }
    }

addItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const {list} = this.state;
  const newItem = this.newItem.value;

  this.setState({
    list: [...this.state.list, newItem]
  })
  this.addForm.reset();
}

render(){
  const {list} = this.state;
    return(
      <div className='list'>
      {
        list.map(item => {
          return <p key={item}>{item}</p>
        })
      }
      <form ref={input => this.addForm = input } onSubmit={(e) => {this.addItem(e)}}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className='sr-only' htmlFor='newItemInput'> </label>
          <input ref={(input) =>{this.newItem = input}} type="text" placeholder="Whats to cool" id='newItemInput' />
          <button type="submit" className="listButton">Add</button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Man, u don't have to put here all the code u have, just the piece you don't understand. Anyway can u send here a live demo?

Comment: sure what do you mean by live demo?

Comment: go to codesandbox and paste your code there or just push it there from gihub for example

Comment: Hi here is the link to codesandbox https://ycego.csb.app/

Comment: so when I click on Brands I would like to display a different list to that of Restaurants

Comment: here is the actual link to codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jonnypein/list

Comment: k, u just need an array of objects. F.e. you have [{category: 'Brands', items: ['CK', 'Gucci', ...]}, {category: 'Films', items: ['Gladiator', ...], ...}] and then to create a component which takes all the brands creates items in navbar and put there an onClick event, then when the category is clicked it goes to the parent component in state and depending on that renders its items in another child component. I hope it will help u.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-northcutt-bhr14?file=/src/App.js Here u go

Comment: Here is live demo I've just made, hope it helps u : https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-northcutt-bhr14?file=/src/App.js